# WinForms UserControl непонятное поведение

Tags: c#, winforms, usercontrol

Если на пустую форму Winforms положить простой `Label` и задать ему свойство `Dock = Fill` (убрав при этом `AutoSize = true`), то при увеличении размеров формы размер `Label`, как и положено, изменяется.

Если я делаю свой `UserControl` наследником от `Label`, в котором меняю шрифт по событию `OnResize`, и также ложу его на пустую форму и также делаю ему `Dock = Fill`, то почему-то то при увеличении размеров формы размер компонента уменяшается, хотя свойство `Dock = Fill` остаётся.

Почему так? Что-то в макетировании формы? Это можно обойти? В коде `UserControl` ничего больше не происходит.

```
public partial class TestLabel : Label
    {
        public TestLabel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Resize += OnResize;
        }

        private void OnResize(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if ((this.FindForm() != null)  && (!this.DesignMode))
                this.Font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, (float)(this.Font.Size * 1.1), this.Font.Style, this.Font.Unit);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Не имеет значения изменять ли шрифт в методе protected override void OnClientSizeChanged(EventArgs e) или в private void OnResize(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) - как я привёл

Comment: "В коде UserControl ничего больше не происходит" и "partial" - вы ничего не скрываете от нас? :-)

Comment: Ещё нашёл такое замечание: "Notes to Inheritors: When overriding the Dock property in a derived class, use the base class's Dock property to extend the base implementation. Otherwise, you must provide all the implementation. You are not required to override both the get and set methods of the Dock property; you can override only one if needed" в https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dock?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-forms-control-dock. Может иметь отношение к вашей проблеме.

Comment: to rotabor: - Ничего не скрываю. Такой шаблон кода в Visual Studio при создании новыхUserControl. Ещё есть файл дизайнера контрола, но там только 1 строчка убирается(как и советует microsoft в своих примерах)

Comment: to rotabor: что в связи с этим нужно сделать(не понимаю)(у меня же нет "overriding the Dock property")? даже если в метод OnResize после условия поставить this.Dock = base.Dock; то в дебагере base.Dock - всегда Fill, но после отработки всего кода и перемакетирования формы компонент уменьшает свои размеры. Это хорошо заметно при TextAling = MiddleCentre –

Comment: если вы делаете наследника `Label`, то зачем вам `UserControl` с его макетированием и т.д.? `UserControl` нужен для сложных составных контролов, а для расширения функционала существующих контролов достаточно простого наследования без всяких `partial`. Вашу проблему нужно искать в первую очередь в коде дизайнера, который у вас прилепился при создании `UserControl`, который вы потом руками перекроили в наследника Label