# WinForms непонятное поведение

Tags: c#, winforms

Вопрос обсуждался ранее здесь - [WinForms UserControl непонятное поведение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1546126/winforms-usercontrol-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/1562141#1562141).
Если на пустую форму Winforms положить простой Label и задать ему свойство Dock = Fill (убрав при этом AutoSize = true), то при увеличении размеров формы, размер Label, как и положено, изменяется.
Если я делаю свой наследник от Label, в котором меняю шрифт по событию OnResize, и также ложу его на пустую форму и также делаю ему Dock = Fill, то почему-то то при увеличении размеров формы размер компонента не меняется, хотя свойство Dock = Fill остаётся.
вот исправленный код, который всё равно не работает:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProjectTestMyLabel1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Form2 frmMain = new Form2();
            Application.Run(frmMain);
        }
    }

    class Form2 : Form
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be      disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.testLabel1 = new TestLabel();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // testLabel1
            // 
            this.testLabel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.testLabel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.testLabel1.Name = "testLabel1";
            this.testLabel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(275, 83);
            this.testLabel1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.testLabel1.Text = "testLabel1";
            this.testLabel1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            // 
            // Form2
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(275, 83);
            this.Controls.Add(this.testLabel1);
            this.Name = "Form2";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "Form2";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private TestLabel testLabel1;
    }

    public class TestLabel : Label
    {
        public TestLabel()
        {
            // if i comment this line - all OK
            this.Resize += OnResize;
        }

        private void OnResize(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if ((this.FindForm() != null) && (!this.DesignMode))
                this.Font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, (float)(this.Font.Size * 1.1), this.Font.Style, this.Font.Unit);
        }
        
        private void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("New size - " + this.Size.Height.ToString() + "," + this.Size.Width.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста снова. Если комментирую строку в конструкторе TestLabel, то всё работает правильно - при изменении размеров формы, надпись центрируется(формула изменения шрифта потом будет другой), если раскомментировать, то работает не правильно - надпись остаётся на месте, хотя свойство Dock остаётся равным Fill и компонент должен изменять свои размеры. При клике на компонент видно, что размеры не изменяются. Почему? Что сделать, чтоб заработало правильно? Куда смотреть?

Comment: Пробовал. Проблему (изменения размеров контрола) не решает

Comment: Опишите точнее, что вы хотите получить, и чем полученный результат отличается от желаемого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ох уж.
Засада тут:

```
this.Font.Size * 1.1
```

Размер всё время увеличивается вне зависимости от направления изменения размеров элемента.

Дальше сами подумайте, что вам нужно делать.

Размер шрифта должен зависить не от его предыдущего размера, а от первоначального и коэффициента изменения размера элемента (отношение текущего размера к первоначальному).

А вообще, изменение размеров решается по-другому.

Comment: Кстати, а какова дискретность вызова OnResize?

Comment: Изначально я описал, что формула размера шрифта будет другой. Здесь - упрощение для примера. Проблема не в формуле размера шрифта

Comment: А как решается проблема изменения размеров? Неужели нужно анализировать свойство Dock и на каждое его значение пересчитывать размеры контрола? Есть ли более элегантное решение?

Comment: Проблема текущего вашего кода именно в этом.

Comment: Изменение размеров делается автоматически без вашего участия, просто нужно правильно настроить параметры.

Comment: Не понял. Я просто думал, что свойство Dock и делает это - автоматически меняет размеры без моего участия. Я думал, что это поведение наследуется .... Оказывается, что нет .... Нужно настраивать только через Anchor? Печалька .... Нужно сообщать пользователю моего нового компонента, что свойством Dock нельзя пользоваться ....

Comment: rotabor - БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО

Comment: Читайте документацию: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dock?view=netframework-4.8#system-windows-forms-control-dock. Dock и Anchor влияют на одно и то же, и использовать их совместно не получится, будет работать только последняя сделанная настройка. "Нужно сообщать пользователю моего нового компонента, что свойством Dock нельзя пользоваться" - не торопитесь с выводами.

Comment: Документацию прочитал. Ответа на свой вопрос не нашёл. Т.к. свойство Achor в моём коде нигде не упоминается ВООБЩЕ. Поэтому я считал, что изменяя свойство Dock - это и будет "последняя сделанная настройка". Наверное, в этом была моя ошибка